# Accessing weather data with rNOMADS

Tags: r

I was running on a daily basis the following code:

```
library(rNOMADS)

model.urls=GetDODSDates("gfs_0p25")
latest.model=tail(model.urls$url,1)
model.run=GetDODSModelRuns(latest.model)
latest.model.run=head(model.run$model.run,1)
```

Then on August 11th the code stopped running and I received the following error message:

```
Error in basename(gds.alt) : a character vector argument expected
```

I run

`traceback()`

and I got the following response:

```
4: basename(gds.alt)
3: NOMADSRealTimeList("dods", abbrev)
2: unique(NOMADSRealTimeList("dods", abbrev)$url)
1: GetDODSDates("gfs_0p25")
```

Any clues for what changed on August 11th and how to fix the code to be executable again?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the gds link title on https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov has changed from 'OpenDAP-alt' to 'OpenDAP'. Consequently, the following code in the NOMADSRealTimeList function is not executed, causing the error:

```
if(grepl("OpenDAP-alt", gds.alt.tmp)) {
  gds.alt[k] <- stringr::str_replace_all(
    stringr::str_extract(gds.alt.tmp, "\"dods.*\""),
    "\"", "")
}
```

The package maintainer needs to update the code.